# Constructor and array not working, String to String[]

Tags: java, arrays, string, testing, constructor

I'm struggling at the moment to figure out why I cant enter any interests into my constructor when trying to tests it, and receive the error that String cannot be converted to String[]. If you can identify where I'm going wrong it would help me greatly.

```
public class ProfileMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Profile profile1;
    profile1 = new Profile("name" , "town" , "country", "nationality", "dateOfBirth", "socks" );
    System.out.println(profile1.toString());
}
}

    public Profile (String name, String town, String country, String nationality, String dateOfBirth, String [] interests) { 

    this.name = name;
    this.town = town;
    this.country = country;
    this.nationality = nationality;
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    this.interests = interests;

}
```

Comment: Well, yes, `String` and `String[]` are different types and you can't just blithely assign the one to the other, any more than you could assign an `Integer` object to a `String[]` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `[]` after `interests` in The `Profile` constructor, like

```
public Profile (String name, String town, String country, String nationality, 
                String dateOfBirth, String interests[]) { // --> here
```

`String` and `String[]` are not the same thing. When you do

```
this.interests = interests;
```

`this.interest` is an `String[]` and `interest` is a `String`. Therefore, the error.

However, you pass `socks` as `interest`, which is a `String` and not a `String[]`. If you require only one *interest*, then make `String interests []=new String [10];` into `String interest`.

However, if you need multiple *interest*, then pass an *array*, instead of `"socks"`

Comment: how would I pass an array? I was unsure if I needed to just add a string so "socks" was the first thing that came to mind/

Comment: using {"socks"} gives me the error: illegal start of expression

illegal start of type

';' expected

Comment: @j.bow try `new String[]{"socks"}`.

Comment: @j.bow if it helped, consider selecting the answer, or upvoting it by the buttons on the left.

Answer (score 1):

`String[]` and `String` are two different things.

`String[]` is an array of `String` instances and `String` is an instance of `String` class defined as `String str="hello"`

1.The both constructor and new operator should have same type.
You can use var arg if interest is last field can occur multiple of times.

```
public class Profile {
    private String name;
    private String town;
    private String country;
    private String nationality;
    private String dateOfBirth;
    private String[] interests;

    Profile (String name, String town, String country, String nationality, String dateOfBirth, String ... interests) { 
        this.name = name;
        this.town = town;
        this.country = country;
        this.nationality = nationality;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.interests = interests;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your Profile  constructor you have

```
public Profile(... ... String dateOfBirth, String interests) {
            ...
        this.interests = interests;
}
```

interests object is an array so the parameters must be an array too:

```
String[] interests
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `interests` as an array in here:

```
String interests []=new String [10];
```

Then you're trying to attribute a String to that same interests

Either declare interests has a normal String or, in your constructor, do this:

```
String[] interests
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string as parameter "interests" for the method "Profile" instead of a string array.

make the interests a string or pass a string array.